# ArcGIS Pro not displaying shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-pro, display

I am using ArcGIS Pro 1.4 on a laptop with the following specs:

- Windows 10 Home 64-bit
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
- Memory:16 GB @ 1200 MHz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060, 6144 MB (Just updated the driver)

The Shapefile I am trying to display is linked here: [TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip](https://goo.gl/WFLQM6)

When I open in Desktop 10.4 it dispalys fine but in Pro I cannot see the layer.  I can access the attribute table and the information function works just fine.

ArcGIS Pro 1.4
[image: Pro_1.4]

ArcGIS Desktop 10.4
[image: Desktop_10.4]

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shapefile name has a `.` character in it. This is invalid.

The [shapefile specification](https://esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) says file names must start with an alphanumeric character (a–Z, 0–9) and can only contain the characters (a–Z, 0–9, _, -).

Comment: answer below shows that it's this one is not a correct answer, so please change it

Answer (score 2):

I found why your data didn't displaying on ArcGIS Pro.
Your Shapefile name contains special character(-).
Rename your shapefile(dbf,prj,shx,shp) name on Windows Explore.
It will be opened in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thanks for this, a shapefile of mine wouldn't display until I removed a full stop from it's filename. Which is utterly insane...

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this same problem with ArcGIS Pro. A shapefile wouldn't display but would open perfectly fine in both Global Mapper and QGIS. None of the solutions here or elsewhere (e.g. renaming the file, using geometry fixer) worked.

I simply converted the file to GeoJSON in Global Mapper (I assume you could use QGIS too) and converted it back to a shapefile in ArcGIS Pro using the GSON to Features tool. Problem solved.